# PHP/ SQL; using a static user int to select from a range

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently working on a project where the user can input a Zip code,  and the script will query, pull and display data from a database range.

An example would be a user inputs 11110 as their zip code. The script would then search for rows that contain the number out of a possible range (e.g 11000 - 11800) then displays the results that fit the criteria from that table.

There will be no overlap. My first instinct was to create the database so there would be two numbers for each row, and that would create the range. But I'm not entirely sure where to go from there.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: What is the purpose of the range, what results do you want? Normally, you would want a specific result, or returning the closest one depending on what you are searching for. So knowing a bit more might help. As a standard notion, you don't set up two different possible results on one row - a row contains (normally) content that belongs together. Hence, if you want to get the results from what the user enters (`11110`) to `11800`, you would select rows matching the original input, up to a set element. Or something completely different, hence why we should have more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate your column range like for example rangeFrom and rangeTo and then you can validate it in your sql query like :

```
SELECT * FROM tblzipcode WHERE rangeFrom <= 11110 AND rangeTo >= 11110;
```

and then get the result.